# Group by in DAX like in SQL

Tags: sql-server, dax

How can I convert this SQL statement to DAX?

SQL query and tables:

```
select SUM(Kiekis )
from Info
left outer join Prekes on Info.PrekeID = Prekes.PrekeID
left outer join PrekiuGrupes on Prekes.PrekiuGrupeID = PrekiuGrupes.PrekiuGrupeID 
group by PrekiuGrupesID
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax) is the main function to use here.

So this:

```
select SUM(Kiekis )
from Info
left outer join Prekes on Info.PrekeID = Prekes.PrekeID
left outer join PrekiuGrupes on Prekes.PrekiuGrupeID = PrekiuGrupes.PrekiuGrupeID 
group by PrekiuGrupesID
```

would be simply

```
   EVALUATE (
         SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(PrekiuGrupes[PrekiuGrupesID], "TotalKiekis", Sum(Info[Kiekis]) )
   )
```

DAX traverses the active relationships in the model, so there's no need to use explicit JOINs.  And instead of having a structured query language DAX uses function argument types to detect the different "clauses".  The first string argument to `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` indicates the transition from "group by" columns, to pairs of (String,Expression) to specify the result columns.